# Is the bulbourethral (Cowper) gland turned on during puberty or is it on at birth?

Tags: reproduction

I am trying to find information about the bulbourethral (Cowper) gland and if it gets turned on during puberty or not. I tried asking several other online sites and they said they couldn't help. I don't know where to ask or where I could look up the answer.

Comment: What does "on" mean in this context? To my knowledge, the exocrine function of the bulbourethral glands (it's a paired organ) is limited to ejaculation, so I'm not sure what you are expecting that they might be up to at birth.

Comment: @Susan On as in active. So basically, do the glands get activated during puberty? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, because the bulbourethral glands are from accessory glands of the male reproductive system as the seminal vesicles and prostate gland. The male reproductive system starts working at puberty.

Comment: Can you please [edit] you answer to add some references that support it? Reliable sources include books, research articles/reviews and websites of reputed academic/research organizations.